# enable bundleIdCapabilities PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS from app-store-connect-api

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store-connect, cicd, app-store-connect-api

I'm working in a CI/CD for our new app and we are using app store connect API, for now I can create a bundle ID, and enable PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS capability for it but I can't figure out how to configure a bundleId PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS capability certificate?

Note: i can enable PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS capability, but this capability without certificate not work.

Helpfull info:
this is my enable capability payload:

```
{
        data: {
            attributes: {
                capabilityType: 'PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS',
            },
            relationships: {
                bundleId: {
                    data: {
                        id: bundleId,
                        type: 'bundleIds'
                    }
                }
            },
            type: 'bundleIdCapabilities'
        }
    }
```

Expected to be like the app store connect console:
[image: app store connect console bundle push notification capability]

I already did many search around google and here but I didn't found nothing about this. About apple forum i found same posts with similar questions without answers. And yes i send a help request to apple support too.

Comment: check my answer to configure a bundle Id PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS capability certificate @Khalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Apple now have Apns Auth Key, it's not necessary to generate certificates for new bundleIds, and that for now it’s not supported buy AppstoreconnectApi.

So I'll leave this answer as an accepted answer to help those who came from the same dough.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, fully closed Xcode by right click in it, opened again and the mistake disappeared

Answer (score 0):

you have to buy developer membership to configure a push certificate in your developer account "developer.apple.com"
select identifiers then select your app to Edit your App ID Configuration
enable push notification
[image]

then configure

[image]
you have to configure 2 certificates one for development and another for production

[image]

to create the file that you have to upload

- on Mac open Keychain access
- Keychain access >  Certificate assistance > Request Certificate from certificate authority ..
- A window appear about certificate information
  Select saved to disk then continue then Save .. done "this is the file needed to upload on developer account"

after uploading file
[image]

download the generated certificate

check service provider about the certificate formate he wants "you have to configure production certificate to the service provider"

Comment: My friend, I think that you didn't read the question carefully, so please be careful next time, to not gain a negative reputation, as your answer is just helping to lose time.

Comment: I replay by detailed steps to generate a certificate for push notifications, it should be generated for an app to receive notifications, it is not clear that you haven't developer account.

Comment: again, try read and understand the first paragraph of my post

Comment: @khalid yes you are right and I find it interesting to learn new App store apis but also I think that my answer may help others to configure push notifications certificate quickly in a few steps. Thank you

Comment: Yes, thin can help someone that searching to figure out how to configure push notifications certificate from appstoreconnect console, otherwize is time losing.